# MySQL connection and disconnection frequency

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, database-connection

Is it better to open and close a new MySQL connection every time a query is made or to keep the connection open and run multiple queries in a single MySQL session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the connection open and run multiple queries in a single mysql session

Comment: Thanks! Could you please provide arguments?

Comment: Can you provide at least one argument against?

Comment: In order to minimize the value of Aborted clients and Aborted connects which appears to become "red" quite soon after restarting the server. (184 and 547 in 5 days)

Comment: errr... which server you are talking about? Are you sure you are talking of mysql server, not HTTP one? Anyway, how do you think multiplying connects can help?